# CteInsertStrategy can only be used with Dialects that support CTE that can take UPDATE or DELETE statements as well

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, common-table-expression

Hibernate 6.0.1 with PostgreSQL JDBC driver 42.3.5 causes the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
CteInsertStrategy can only be used with Dialects that support CTE that can take UPDATE or DELETE statements as well
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.cte.CteInsertStrategy.<init>(CteInsertStrategy.java:123)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.cte.CteInsertStrategy.<init>(CteInsertStrategy.java:107)
at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.getFallbackSqmInsertStrategy(PostgreSQLDialect.java:704)
...
```

What's wrong and how can I fix the issue?

MyEntity.java

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity")
public class MyEntity {

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_sequence", sequenceName = "my_id_sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "id_sequence")
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

MyTest.java

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
import org.junit.*;

public class MyTest {

    private static Configuration configuration;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    private Session session;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        session.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
        session.persist(entity);
        assertNotNull(entity.getId());
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">30</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">120</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property>
    <mapping class="haba713.MyEntity" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    hibernateVersion = '6.0.1.Final'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.5'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-c3p0:' + hibernateVersion
    implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:' + hibernateVersion
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}
```

See the full source code [here](https://github.com/haba713/hibernate-cte-insert-strategy-issue).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The configuration property `use_jdbc_metadata_defaults` must be `true` for Hibernate to detect the correct version of the PostgreSQL dialect.

Removing this line

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
```

from `hibernate.cfg.xml` resolves the issue.

(Thanks to Christian at [Hibernate Zulip channel](https://hibernate.zulipchat.com) for sorting this out.)

Comment: In my case the cause was simpler and less obvious: wrong password for connecting user

Comment: In my case the cause was even simpler and should have been more obvious: PostgreSQL wasn't running...

Comment: My case is similar to @EduardDrenth case, but it is mainly because I have a Postgresql service that will automatically be run on system start-up, meanwhile, the Postgresql I intend to use is docker-compose PostgreSQL. Both Postgresql uses the same port, and neither shows an error due to this port conflict.

Comment: In my spring boot application I had 'use_jdbc_metadata_defaults' in 'application.yaml' file.

Answer (score 4):

The same error i got when used wrong hibernate dialect, in my case: `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect` instead of `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` on PostgreSQL v12.

Answer (score 2):

Adding **allocationsize=1** solved my issue

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sq_seq", initialValue = 99999, allocationSize = 1)
```